# Opening Excel file in IE provokes three logons?

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, authentication, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP website that posts a form to a page that then generates and streams an Excel file out to users. Actually, its a raw HTML table which I send with:

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file.xls"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

The intranet website is secured via integrated windows authentication. No other access mode is checked. The user logs in with their network password and all is well.

Now, when the user submits the form, this action results in two more login dialogs. You can actually cancel out of both and still open the file. In fact, if you put in your credentials, it requires you to enter them four times! If you check "Remember password", it doesn't affect the need for logging in. Also, this happens even if the URLs are listed on the Trusted Sites section of IE.

Any ideas on what I can do to minimize this?

PS: Not sure, but seems to be a relatively recent issue, meaning a more recent version of IE (7/8), Office (2007+) and or Windows (Vista/7).

UPDATE: Using Fiddler, I can see that something called "User-Agent: Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7600" is attempting to connect, and getting 401.2'ed. Is IE offloading the download to something else that isn't authenticating properly?

UPDATE2: Doubly-interestingly, Firefox does none of this. It receives and interprets things properly:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 19:25:26 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="SavingsReport_4Q2010.xls"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Length: 111851
Cache-control: private
```

Comment: can we get an update or kill the question?

Comment: IE tries to find out if this is a Sharepoint site with Option requests. You better not challenge these request but send a 404.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but here goes in case someone else stumbles on it.

Office tries to authenticate with the file server, through an OPTIONS request, in order to access the file as explained on this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019105/en-gb).

Without entirely understanding why, changing your content-disposition from `inline` to `attachment` will not prompt for authentication in most environments.

Be careful as this seems to have an effect on the file's name (on win XP - IE7.
E.g. file with name `file name.xls` would be opened as `file_name.xls`

Here is example classic ASP Code:

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyReport.xls"
```